# QT + boost-thread not working

Tags: qt, boost-thread

I'm writing a code using both Qt and boost.

I know that qt window **needs to be started in the main thread**, so, I'm trying to run some code in another thread using boost (not QThread).

The problem is, if I run my code without starting the qt window, it works perfectly fine, however, if I call the app.exec(), the other thread (the boost one) stops working. I don't know what is happening, any clues?

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);
QMainWindow window;

//creating a separated thread and starting up
boost::thread thr1( boost::bind( &X::x, &a ) );

//if we join, it works
//thr1.joing()

//but if I run the following lines, my thr1 freezes
window.show();
app.exec();
```

Comment: how do you link boost thread? I know there are some problems on windows if you link statically.

Comment: I'm linking using cmake, in my CMakeLists.txt I have
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( project ${Boost_LIBRARIES} )
And it works If I do not start qt =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was with my boost implementation. I fixed recompiling it